# Ubuntu 16.04 Boot problem, possible due to gpu drivers

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

since yesterday I have troubles to boot my ubuntu. It stacks on loading screen (purple window) and does nothing. The only way to get into system is use emergency mode and **systemctl defualt** but its really annoying. I had Xorg nouveau drivers when it started to happening, so I reinstalled to nvidia, it were even worse. With NVIDIA drivers (even with secure boot disabled) I couldn't even go to emergency mode and had to fix it via LiveCD, but then I returned to previous situation. I think I really tried all solutions which I found on this page.

I should also mention that I am using GRUB where I have also Windows as boot device

Also when booting it says error like: **failed to add i915 component master (-19)**

I really have no more idea how to solve that problem, will appreciate any help or ideas.

Thanks

Output from **lshw -c video** under super-user

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 940M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```